# BufferOverflowException in java threads

Tags: java, sikuli

Receiving an exception "BufferOverflowException" while running sikuli script via threads. The same script works properly without thread object. I have no clue what causes the bufferoverflowexception. Please guide.

**Sample Code:-**

```
import org.sikuli.script.*;  // Library import
    
public class Sikuli {

    private Screen screen = new Screen();

    private Pattern getPattern(String imagePath) {
        return new Pattern(imagePath);
    }
    
    public void click(String imagePath) throws FindFailed, InterruptedException {
         screen.click(getPattern(imagePath));
    }
    
    public void sendKeys(String value) {
        screen.type(value);
    }

import Sukuli // Custom sikuli class import

public class foo {
    
     Sikuli sk = new Sikuli();
     
    public void test() {     
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
               sk.click(new Pattern("imagePath"));
               sk.type("fooboo");
            });
            t1.start();
        }
}
```

**From Sikuli Library Methods which are being referred by my class methods:-**

```
 public int type(String text) {
        try {
            return this.keyin((Object)null, text, 0);
        } catch (FindFailed var3) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

private <PFRML> int keyin(PFRML target, String text, int modifiers) throws FindFailed {
        if (target != null && 0 == this.click(target, 0)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            Debug profiler = Debug.startTimer("Region.type", new Object[0]);
            if (text != null && !"".equals(text)) {
                String showText = "";

                for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
                    showText = showText + Key.toJavaKeyCodeText(text.charAt(i));
                }

                String modText = "";
                String modWindows = null;
                if ((modifiers & 4) != 0) {
                    modifiers -= 4;
                    modifiers |= 4;
                    log(3, "Key.WIN as modifier", new Object[0]);
                    modWindows = "Windows";
                }

                if (modifiers != 0) {
                    modText = String.format("( %s ) ", KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(modifiers));
                    if (modWindows != null) {
                        modText = modText.replace("Meta", modWindows);
                    }
                }

                Debug.action("%s TYPE \"%s\"", new Object[]{modText, showText});
                log(3, "%s TYPE \"%s\"", new Object[]{modText, showText});
                profiler.lap("before getting Robot");
                IRobot r = this.getRobotForRegion();
                int pause = 20 + (Settings.TypeDelay > 1.0 ? 1000 : (int)(Settings.TypeDelay * 1000.0));
                Settings.TypeDelay = 0.0;
                profiler.lap("before typing");
                r.typeStarts();

                for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
                    r.pressModifiers(modifiers);
                    r.typeChar(text.charAt(i), KeyMode.PRESS_RELEASE);
                    r.releaseModifiers(modifiers);
                    r.delay(pause);
                }

                r.typeEnds();
                profiler.lap("after typing, before waitForIdle");
                r.waitForIdle();
                profiler.end();
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Trace logs:-**

```
[log] CLICK on L[1517,53]@S(0) (555 msec)[log]  TYPE "fooboo"Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:521)
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.stream.AbstractStreamEncoder.encodeString(AbstractStreamEncoder.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.stream.AbstractStreamEncoder.encodeStringData(AbstractStreamEncoder.java:171)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.stream.AbstractStreamEncoder.encode(AbstractStreamEncoder.java:157)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.spi.EventChannelEncoder.encodeMessage(EventChannelEncoder.java:398)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.spi.EventChannelEncoder.setOutErr(EventChannelEncoder.java:188)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.spi.EventChannelEncoder.testOutput(EventChannelEncoder.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.booter.ForkingRunListener.writeTestOutput(ForkingRunListener.java:113)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.booter.ForkingRunListener.writeTestOutput(ForkingRunListener.java:44)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4RunListener.writeTestOutput(JUnit4RunListener.java:235)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.report.ConsoleOutputCapture$ForwardingPrintStream.println(ConsoleOutputCapture.java:144)
        at org.sikuli.basics.Debug.log(Debug.java:881)
        at org.sikuli.basics.Debug.action(Debug.java:645)
        at org.sikuli.script.Region.keyin(Region.java:4613)
        at org.sikuli.script.Region.type(Region.java:4493)
        at Sikuli.sendKeys(Sikuli.java:87)
```

Comment: can you add all the code or upload in github?

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez: Added (Mocked code) as requested! This issue raises only when methods are called under java thread object.